# Include whole object in Pydantic ValidationError

Tags: pydantic

Pydantic will by default show an error message like this

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Room members -> 0
```

which is fine if you're say dealing with say an API request and can just add a top-level try catch and print out any other metadata you need like the request. However if you're loading many records from at once you now don't know which record is causing the issue and need to add a try catch within a loop every time you call `Class.parse_obj(..)`.

**Is there a way to have pydantic print out the whole object it's trying to validate, not just the fields that are invalid?**

I tried adding a wrapper with a try catch, but pydantic doesn't like that I'm adding an unfamiliar keyword ("got an unexpected keyword argument 'skip'")

```
@validator("*", pre=True, each_item=True)
def add_debug_info(
    cls,
    value: Any,
    field: Any,
    values: Mapping[str, Any],
    **kwargs: Dict[str, Any],
):
    if not kwargs.get("skip"):
        try:
            field.validate(
                value, {}, loc=field.alias, cls=cls, skip=True
            )
        except error_wrappers.ValidationError as e:
            raise ValueError(f"custom error message {values}")

    return value
```

Comment: Less prose, more code. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76135163/edit) your post and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the output you are _actually getting_ and include the output you would _like to get_ as well. Your failed attempt at a validator is less helpful than a complete and clear-cut MRE.